# 'far from obvious' or 'far from being obvious'

Tags: word-usage, grammar

It is a scientific paper. I would like to say

> This fact is far from being obvious.

Can I delete the 'being'? Initially I used it because I thought it should be a noun behind the 'from'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can delete the from. Although both forms sound okay, I think without the from is better and sounds like like idomatic english.

Comment: you mean deleting 'being'?

Comment: Yes ...........